# Is there a polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients that satisfies $P(2)=4$ and $P(6)=6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

What I did so far:
I imagened a polynomial $P(x)$ with degree of $n$.
$P(6)=a_n6^n + \dots + a_26^2 + a_16 + a_0$

$P(2)=a_n2^n +\dots+ a_22^2 + a_12 + a_0$

$P(6) - P(2) =a_n(6^n - 2^n) +\dots + a_2(6^2 -2^2) + a_1(6 - 2) +0$

I have found out that $a^n - b^n$ will always be divisible by $a-b$.
If I can prove that, then I know that $P(6) - P(2)$ has to be divisible by $6-2=4$.
But I don’t know how to easily prove that.

Comment: Hint:  you can write down the quotient explicitly.

Comment: Deduce a contradiction by apply the Factor Theorem as in the linked dupes.

Answer (score 1):

You are around the corner for the answer. What you showed is that $4 = (6-2) \mid (P(6) - P(2)) = 6 - 4 = 2$ which is a contradiction. So no such polynomial exist.

Comment: Yeah I know that its contradiction.I pardon for not being more precise.I am not sure how to prove that $a^n - b^n$ will always be divisible by $a-b$

Comment: @RogerPowell setting $a=b$ gives $0$ and thus $a-b$ must be a factor

Comment: Yeah.It was so simple that I am emberessed.Even chatgpt could undersyand it.Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)